# Converting digits to words in a string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string and want to integrate throw it and convert its digits into English words. For example, If string is "`I ran 12 miles`", I want to convert "`12`" to "`OneTwo`" and return "`I ran OneTwo miles`". I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I tried a for loop and went through all the characters but it didn't let me replace a character with a substring

Comment: Take a look at String class documentation. You should fin method like `replace`. Try using it. Come back when you will have specific problem with your code.

Comment: Create map of numbers to names.  Then you will have to parse the input text, extract the numbers, and replace with names.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Comment: @Pshemo how do you do that? The off-topic flagging panel doesn't have such option. Have you chosen any other off-topic flag?

Comment: @YakovL When you have at least [3000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you no longer need to flag for review, but you can cast closing votes (5 needed to put question on hold). One of closing option is "Off-topic ..." and then you can select more appropriate reason, but since not all reasons are there there, we have option for custom reason. When such vote is cast system will also automatically post comment in form `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [your custom reason]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the method you're looking for: [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: You are saying `replace` but linking to `replaceAll`. Is it intentional?

Answer (score 1):

The UTF-16 code unit of character `0 TO 9` is between `48 and 57`, so what you need to do is to parcourire your String and check if the code is between this two numbers, so if yes than replace it with another String,

This piece of code will help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String p = "I ran 12 miles";
    String[] numbersC = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
    String newP = "";
    int ci;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
        ci = (int) p.charAt(i);
        if (ci >= 48 && ci <= 57) {
            newP += numbersC[Character.getNumericValue(p.charAt(i))];
        } else {
            newP += p.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newP);
}
```

Comment: Please do explain a bit. Code-only answers do not help anyone  :)

Comment: You must have meant 0 to 9. But, it's better to just write `ci >= '0' && ci <= '9'`. (BTW—Java doesn't use ASCII; it uses Unicode. Change "code ASCII" to "UTF-16 code unit" and your statement would still be correct.)

Comment: yes you are True @Tom Blodget i maked a typos excuse me

Answer (score 0):

use this code to convert number to word (It does not satisfy your actual need, but you should try it with your self) :-

```
public class NumberToWord  
{
private static final String[] numNames = {
    "zero",
    " one",
    " two",
    " three",
    " four",
    " five",
    " six",
    " seven",
    " eight",
    " nine",
};
public String convert(int number) {

    if (number == 0) { return "zero"; }

    String prefix = "";

    if (number < 0) {
        number = -number;
        prefix = "negative";
    }

    String current = "";

    do {
        int n = number % 10;
        current = numNames[n] + current;
        number /= 10;
    } while (number > 0);

    return (prefix + current).trim();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberToWord obj = new NumberToWord();
    System.out.println("*** " + obj.convert(123456789));
    System.out.println("*** " + obj.convert(-55));
}
```

}

Comment: Can someone please tell me the reason of down vote ?

Comment: Please reread the question. Your code will convert `12` to twelve, not `OneTwo` like OP wants.

Comment: @Vishal thanks.I just need to replace digits 0-9 with words.